# change data of all line in erlang

Tags: erlang

I have two table **sms_sent**  and **sms_sent_backup**

the format of sms_sent and sms_sent_backup   are :

```
 -record(sms_sent, {id, text}).
  -record(sms_sent_backup, {id, text}).
```

sms_sent contains this values in the mnesia

```
1     test1

2     test2

3     test3
```

and sms_sent_backup contains this values in the mnesia

```
8     hi

9     hello
```

I want to develop a function that will retrieve the last id of sms_sent_backup (the value **9**)
 after that I want to change the all id of sms_sent , the new values of this id is the previous values + the value 9 (the last id of sms_sent_backup)

mean the new format of sms_sent is :

```
10     test1

11     test2

12     test3
```

I try to get the last key of **sms_sent_backup** but I have this error

```
 1> model:testkey().
** exception exit: {aborted,no_transaction}
     in function  mnesia:abort/1
```

I test with this function :

```
testkey()->
    LastKey = mnesia:last(sms_sent_backup).
```

but I want to say that **sms_sent_backup**  contains the key but not in order

meaning for example **sms_sent_backup** contains this values :

```
    8     hi

    9     hello

    11     hi1

    10     hello1
```

so I need to have this value :  **11**   from the table  **sms_sent_backup**

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this

1. If your sms_sent_backup table is of type ordered_set, then you can do `LastKey = mnesia:last(sms_sent_backup).` This will give you last key value. Later you can do LastKey + 1 while inserting a new record.
2. During each insert store the value of the key in you local state and use it for inserting the next record. For the first time you can do mnesia:foldl to find the largest.
3. Have your own mnesia counter table created using `mnesia:create_table(my_auto_inc,[{type,set}]).`. During insertion to your backup table you can do`NextKey =  mnesia:dirty_update_counter(my_auto_inc,lastrec,1).` which you can use to insert the new record.